# Python CTypes Segmentation/Bus Errors

Tags: python, c++, macos, c++14, ctypes

Edit:

`detector_new` used to `return new Detector();` and it failed very frequently maybe 3 / 5 times.

The code below fails much less often perhaps 1 / 20 times.

If I return the address to _this it never seems to fail.

```
Detector _this;

extern "C"
{
    void *detector_new()
    {
        return new Detector;
        // return &_this;
    }
```

Original Question:

My OS X C++/Python simulation code sometimes works and sometimes generates segmentation faults and bus errors. I've tried to carefully define arguments and return types for `ctypes`. My application types like `U16` map to corresponding values in `<stdint.h>`.

It seems to not like this C++ class method:

```cpp
void consider(U16 a, U16 b, U16 c);
```

It's wrapped as follows for a dylib...

```cpp
using DetectorP = Detector *;

void detector_consider(void *d, U16 a, U16 b, U16 c)
{
    DetectorP(d)->consider(a, b, c);
}
```

...and is defined in Python using `ctypes` as:

```py
_library = cdll.LoadLibrary('libhail.dylib')

f = _library.detector_consider

f.restype = None

f.argtypes = [c_voidp, c_ushort, c_ushort, c_ushort]
```

I'm building the library in this manner:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

clang++ -c -g -DSIMULATION -I. -I../Application -I../Application/Precipitation Interface.cpp ../Application/Precipitation/Hail.cpp -std=c++14

clang++ -o libhail.dylib -dynamiclib Hail.o Interface.o
```